# SSH No Route to Host

Tags: networking, ssh, server, local, sshd

I apologize for the novice question, but have been struggling on this for many hours. I am running Ubuntu Server on Ubuntu 16.04. I can ssh fine into local host (thus know ssh server is running)
[image]

However, when I try to log into my server externally, I get the error message shown below (yes I know port 22 is not secure):
[image]

I have enabled port 22 on my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and allowed the ListenAddress to be everything by leaving it empty (tried with other addresses), and ensured that my iptables are open:
[image]

Finally, I am using a static IP address. And ensuring that I am forwarding ports:
[image]

I am not including a port triggering as I do not believe that it is necessary?

What do I need to do to expose this server externally and be able to SSH into it? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I know that I can ping my IP address, and have restarted my router.

Comment: just curious, is internet access provided via router? If so, have you forward the ports on that? is it an ipv4 external address or ipV6? Ping will only show that the external address exists (assuming that the router is set to return them). It won't show that the forwarding is correct.

Comment: Yes internet access is being provided via the router. Yes I have forwarded the ports on that. ipv4 external and static. I am able to ping the ip address with no problems. +Edit added static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, no responses required. My internal ip address that I had my port forwarding selected for was different than the internal ip address that my computer was on.